# Whats ist the difference between these two javaScript syntaxes?

Tags: javascript

Both of them works without errors, is there any difference?

```
(function(){}());

(function (){})();
```

here are some working examples:

```
    console.log(
            (function (a) {return a*2;}(3))
    );

    console.log(
            (function (a) {return a*2;})(3)
    );
```

Comment: both are the same. just coder preference what you choose.

Comment: No differences, you may also do that aswell: `~function(a){ return a*2; }(3);` these all are auto-executing anynomous functions, you may find even other ways they are written according to the programmer or, occasionally, according to the minifier the programmer used. You may want to either check james's link or this for  more cases: https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess both are same, only thing is one is wrapped inside parantheses `()` and the other is not.

```
(function(){}());
```

And this is creating and executing it immediately:

```
(function (){})();
```

Example for the second case would be:

```
function sayHello () {
  alert("Hello");
}
sayHello ();
```

The above is equivalent:

```
(function () {
  alert("Hello");
})();
```

Both are the same, it is just the preference of coding style.

Comment: `(function(){})();` ist that not the same?

Comment: but both of them execute immediately in the js-debugger?

Comment: @Vienna Sorry, updated the answer. Looks like both are the same.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Updated the answer. Sorry!!!

Comment: delete the answer and give close vote to the question in favor of already existed question.